# How to setup CUPS to keep a log of how many pages I printed?

Tags: logs, printing, cups

I have a Debian computer setup with CUPS. I need to record how many pages I'm printing, for work. Is there a way to set up CUPS to store a log each time I print, with the quantity of pages printed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CUPS is on Linux, installed with all components into their default path. Then have a look at the file

```
/var/log/cups/page_log
```

This file holds all information about jobs having been completed by CUPS. To understand the file's format, have a look at

- http://localhost:631/help/ref-page_log.html or
- https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-cupsd-logs/

Each line in the file tells you for each job, copy and page the following info (if it's format is not customized):

1. Printer Name
2. User Name
3. Job-ID
4. Date+Time of Printout
5. Page Number
6. Copy Number
7. Job Billing Info (if submitted)
8. Print Client's Host Name
9. Job Name (if provided)
10. Media Name (if provided)
11. Sides: one- or two-sided? (if provided)

Comment: CUPS is not storing these files. Is there a way to turn this log on?